# Bitcoin millionaire pro

Tags: mining-profitability

Can someone earn bitcoins for free by using bitcoin millionaire pro platform really?
I have just come across this ad somewhere. And I thought of inquiring about it to have some clue about it.

Comment: That's almost definitely a scam

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it is scam. Some explanations in link

> https://binarysignalsadvise.com/bitcoin-millionaire-pro-review-scam/

Answer (score 0):

Although I do not endorse the review, I did find the results on the is-scam.com website intersting: [review](https://www.is-scam.com/system-scam-reviews/bitcoin-millionaire-pro/?keyword=&adpos=1t1&ad=166694932501&matchtype=b&device=c&gclid=CjwKCAjwt5DXBRAtEiwAa3vyElp-3oXxCJQrHlAM4_RPMROQQVJBBoQxTuYgShaRKswLcvOpT0EPNhoCyDkQAvD_BwE#conclusion)

> ## Final Verdict
>
> Bitcoin Millionaire Pro is a cheap and unauthentic online trading system that wants to trick unsuspecting people into registering for it. There are many similar scams out there and our job is to make sure that you will be informed about them on time, in order to avoid any contact with fraudulent trading products. So, make sure to regularly check our site and read the newest product reviews we upload for you.